# Как сделать перезапуск Python программы?

Tags: python

Я ещё только учу Python. Написал для себя маленькую программу, что-то вроде конвертера валют, только для игры. Через PyInstaller сделал exe программы, но после вывода результата окно сразу закрывается. как сделать, что бы окно не закрывалось и была возможность начать заново, что бы для каждого расчёта не запускать программу по новой?

```
currency = float(input("Введите количество валюты: "))
price = float(input("Введите цену валюты: "))
total = currency * price
x = currency * price
while int(x) < total:
    currency = currency - 1
    total = currency * price
print("Вы получите", int(total + price), "хаосов за", int(currency + 1))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самое простое - обернуть всю логику в бесконечный цикл while:

```
while True:
    currency = float(input("Введите количество валюты: "))
    price = float(input("Введите цену валюты: "))
    total = currency * price
    x = currency * price
    while int(x) < total:
        currency = currency - 1
        total = currency * price
    print("Вы получите", int(total + price), "хаосов за", int(currency + 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Есть альтернативное решение:

```
import os
import sys

os.execl(sys.executable, sys.executable, *sys.argv)
```

В данном случае оно конечно не будет удобно, но иногда хорошо.